Have finished replacing drop ceiling. Pesent insulation is R19 face down. Should I use unfaced as a second layer perpendicular?
Have replaced drop ceiling & insulated R19 face down. Should the 2nd layer perpendicular be unfaced?

You only want a single vapour(face) barrier.  Can have has many unfaced layers as you want
